# Windows 8.1 start-up logo replaced with ASUS logo after BIOS update

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, asus-laptop, zenbook

I have an ASUS Zenbook and flashed the BIOS to the latest version from the ASUSTek support website.

After completion, I saw that the Windows 8.1 logo at startup was replaced by an ASUS one.

How can I get the Windows 8 logo back?

Comment: ASUS has a utility to allow you to do this on their website

Comment: I just checked all their utilities downloads for my laptop and didn't see any saying it would revert the logo change. Where should I look?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand what you lost exactly.  What logo exactly was replaced?  I thought you were talking about the BIOS logo which is ASUS has a tool to customize ( perhaps not with the Zenbook ).

Comment: It's the logo you see with the loading animation when the operating system starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is the **Boot(time) Graphics Resource Table (BGRT) Logo** which is installed into the UEFI. I can turn this logo off on my Dell Laptop, by enabling the **VGA option ROM loading**, which disabled the BRGT feature and now you have the Windows Logo back.

Comment: I wonder if Microsoft aren't pissed off. Anyway, where should I look for this? In the BIOS settings?

Comment: Also, if I were to do that (hoping there's a similar setting on ASUS laptops), it would only change the logo and not affect anything else, right?

Comment: no, they want that the OEM logo is shown. In the Demo video of MS you also only see the HP logo: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/08/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8.aspx. This option only changes the way the logo is displayed.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look in the BIOS settings as soon as I can.

Comment: There's nothing I can see in the BIOS GUI that affects that. Is there any other way?

Comment: ask the ASUS support for help. I don't have an ASUS, so I can't help.

Comment: Yup, I've already sent them an email, I was wondering if there's like 3rd party tools or such that can enable me to do it myself. Thanks.