# Change boot logo in Windows 8.1 HP

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

I have a bit of a problem. When I start up my computer, I get your standard HP boot logo.

I've seen that on other PC's they were able to simply use boot logo changer, and it would work.

I tried doing it manually. So, I opened bootres.dll, and extracted the files from it, and I got [these images](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/a8ct4651gk73t5w/Boot%20Logo.zip). I wanted these images in the first place, but, when I did another soft shutdown, it was still the HP logo.

So, how do I fix this?

```
Product name:HP 15 Notebook PC 
Product number:J8X12UA#ABA
BIOS (Configuration):F.04-08/25/2014 (096A100003405F00050660180)
Keyboard revision:06.06
Total memory:4.00 GB
Processor name:Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N2840  @ 2.16GH
```

Comment: Do you see an HP logo and then later the Windows boot logo or just an HP logo? If it's the former, it's probably a BIOS splash screen and not the ordinary Windows one. In that case you'll want this: http://superuser.com/questions/116507/how-can-i-change-my-bios-splashscreen

Comment: I only see the HP logo. :/

Comment: Okay, there was a similar question for ASUS here: http://superuser.com/questions/665832/windows-8-1-start-up-logo-replaced-with-asus-logo-after-bios-update They recommend you contact the manufacturer yourself as this process most likely would not be the same as changing the normal Windows boot logo.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tool called HackBGRT: https://github.com/Metabolix/HackBGRT

That should make it super easy to change your boot image. Make sure to disable secure boot if needed, and make sure the image you use is in 24-bit BMP/DIB format.

This has worked for me in the past, persisting across boots, But NOT after upgrades. If you reset your PC or upgrade your version of Windows, note that it will reset the boot image to default